# Null HttpSessionManager with HeaderHttpSessionStrategy in Spring session

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-session

I've a problem with spring-session to allow multiple sessions in same browser. I'm using MapSessionRepository to store sessions and CookieHttpSessionStrategy. With this configutation everything's working fine.

I've been asked to change CookieHttpSessionStrategy to HeaderHttpSessionStrategy. Now I get a NullPointerException when I try to get HttpSessionManager from request.

This is my previous config (I'ts working):

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.company.name" }, excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = { "com.company.name.web*" }))
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableCaching
@EnableSpringHttpSession
public class Config {
    ....
    ....
    @Bean
    public MapSessionRepository sessionRepository() {
        return new MapSessionRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
        return new CookieHttpSessionStrategy(); 
    }
}
```

This is my **new** config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.company.name" }, excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = { "com.company.name.web*" }))
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableCaching
@EnableSpringHttpSession
public class Config {
    ....
    ....
    @Bean
    public MapSessionRepository sessionRepository() {
        return new MapSessionRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy(); 
    }
}
```

I get SessionManager object with:

```
//Se obtiene el manager de sesiones de spring session
HttpSessionManager sessionManager = (HttpSessionManager) httpRequest.getAttribute(HttpSessionManager.class.getName());
```

When I use header strategy there's no org.springframework.session.web.http.HttpSessionManager attribute on request. Am I doing something wrong? I thought I could change my strategy just returning a HeaderHttpSessionStrategy object or implementing a new custom strategy.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why are you even obtaining the `HttpSessionManager` like that? If you need it just inject it...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to look at the source code of `SessionRepositoryFilter` class to understand why the session manager is null. You will observe that it by default uses `CookieHttpSessionStrategy`. The `CookieHttpSessionStrategy` has a `wrapRequest` method which sets the sessionManager attribute on the request.

If you inject any other strategy to the session filter then it uses a `MultiHttpSessionStrategyAdapter` static class which wont set the `SessionManager`. That's the reason you are getting this as null.

EDIT:

You can get the Session Manager by getting the bean reference as below:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(httpRequest.getServletContext());
HttpSessionManager sessionManager = ctx.getBean(HttpSessionManager.class);
```

In essence, you are getting the reference of the 'httpSessionStrategy' bean you had defined in your config.

Comment: It turns out that Spring Session doesn't support multiple sessions with HeaderHttpSessionStrategy. I used HttpSessionStrategy  instead